# how to pause a running animation and run another animation with one button in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

On the homepage I have a group of animated divs running, what I like to do is increase the interactivity by animating additional elements on the page once the user clicks one of the main navigational links, but I would like the initial group animations to stop and new group of animations to begin with one click of the main navigation. Any one have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Post the code you're working with currently.

Comment: do you mind sharing what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can "pause" an animation using `animation-play-state` but if you just want one animation to run, then when you click on something, you want another animation to run, you can just apply classes that change the `animation` property of the element.

```js
$('button').on('click',function() {
  $('#div').toggleClass('red');
})
```

```css
div {
  animation: blue 1s infinite;
}
.red {
  animation: red 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes blue {
  50% {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
  }
}

@keyframes red {
  50% {
    background: red;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
<div id="div">red</div>
```